# How to Redirect to queried URL after authentication in nodejs

Tags: node.js, redirect, passport.js

I am making a Video Chat app, in which user can share the link of the meeting when another person accesses the meeting link and if not authenticated then I redirect to the login page using passportjs, but when user logins, then it goes to the home page rather than meeting URL, how can I redirect to meeting URL after authentication.

Answer (score 1):

The common solution is to add a **query param** that holds the redirect path.

```
const redirectLink = encodeURI(`/my-chat-room.com`); // important to encode the link
res.redirect("/login?redirect=" + redirectLink);
```

Then you can check in your `/login` handler method if the **redirect** parameter exsist and use it to redirect the client.
If it doesn't exist use `/home` as default.

try it with google:

1. Get a google app link (like a doc link)
2. Open an incognito tab and use the link (you will be redirected to Google login page).
3. Check the URL for the `continue` query param